# Как добавить текст из заголовка h1 в input с определенным ID при клике по ссылке

Tags: javascript

**Здравствуйте!**
Есть следующая конструкция:

```css
div {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Заголовок страницы</h1>
  <a href="#" class="link"> Заказать</a>
</div>

<div class="form">
  <input placeholder="Наименование" id="pn" type="text">
</div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как без использования jquery, а только с помощью javascript при клике по ссылке с классом `link` вставить текст из h1 в input с id `pn`  ??

Как должен выглядеть такой скрипт?

**Благодарю за ответ!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('a.link').addEventListener('click', () => {
    let h = document.querySelector('h1').textContent;
    document.getElementById('pn').value = h;
})
```

```css
div {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Заголовок страницы</h1>
    <a href="#" class="link"> Заказать</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form">
    <input placeholder="Наименование" id="pn" type="text">
  </div>
```

Или еще короче и без переменных:

```
document.querySelector('a.link').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('pn').value = document.querySelector('h1').textContent;
})
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за быстрый ответ и рабочее решение! Все заработало! 2 часа пытался сам решить такую простую задачу , в итоге решил спросить)

Comment: В JS уже давно добавлены многие фишки jQuery. Одна из них - `querySelector` и `querySelectorAll`. Вместо `.on` можно использовать `.addEventListener` - длиннее, но суть почти та же. Просто `$()` возвращает коллекцию, которой можно в группе назначить слушателей, а в Vanillajs перебором каждому элементу в отдельности.